# How can I get link to specific tweet?

Tags: html

I need to know if there is a way to get link to specific tweet (`url`).
I want to link one of the tweets on my website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://support.twitter.com/articles/80586

Linking to an individual Tweet or Moment
Did you know you can link to a Tweet or Moment, just like you link to a webpage? Every Tweet and Moment has its own URL that you can bookmark or share with friends.

How to find a Tweet's URL:
On the web:

Locate the Tweet anywhere on twitter.com.
Click the ••• More icon located within the Tweet.
From the menu that pops up, select Copy link to Tweet.
A prompt will display the link to the Tweet so you can copy it to your clipboard.

In the Twitter app (iOS or Android):

Locate the Tweet.
Tap the Tweet. This will bring you to the Tweet detail view.
Next, tap the more icon •••  (iOS) or the overflow icon  (Android).
Select Copy link to Tweet. The URL should now be copied to your clipboard.

Whenever you view a Tweet's permanent link, you can see:

The exact time and date the Tweet was posted.
The number of favorites and retweets the Tweet received.
How to find a Moment’s URL:
On the web:

Go to the Moments tab 
Click on the Moment and find its URL in the address bar of your web browser.

In the Twitter app (iOS or Android)

Go to the Moments tab 
Tap the Moment and swipe left to view the story.
When you get to the end, tap Share.
The Tweet compose view will open and include the URL to the Moment you want to share.
Having trouble?
Explore our troubleshooting articles for solutions to common problems.

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: At least someone helped instead of deleting "Thank you in advance." and moaning for giving links that actually helped.